# I cant receive anything other than text files

Tags: c#, image, sockets

I have tried every solution I could find but nothing seems to work. Anything other than text files becomes corrupted; someone said that TCP can't send more than 8KB, so I tried to fix the problem and I think I did. Now, when I send a text file (no matter what size it is), it reaches perfectly but anything else gets corrupted. I know the code for the cutting is expensive to performance but I am going to think about that later.

Here is my sender code:

```
private string SendFile(string tosend, string tosendname)
{
    ipadd = IPAddress.Parse(textBox2.Text);
    ep = new IPEndPoint(ipadd, 6112);
    Sender = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
    Sender.Connect(ep);
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    byte[] filetosend = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(tosend);
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(tosend, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    //Read byte from image
    fs.Read(filetosend, 0, filetosend.Length);
    fs.Flush();
    fs.Close();
    int countt = filetosend.Count();
    int dividedcount = countt / 7000;
    Sender.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("filesize#" + filetosend.Count().ToString()));
    Thread.Sleep(500);
    List<byte> cuttedtosend = new List<byte>();
    for (int counti = 0; counti < dividedcount; counti++)
    {
        cuttedtosend = new List<byte>();
        for (int index = 0; index < 7000; index++)
        {
            cuttedtosend.Add(filetosend[(filetosend.Count() - countt) + index]);
        }
        Sender.Send(cuttedtosend.ToArray());
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        countt -= 7000;
        richTextBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { richTextBox1.AppendText("Countt = " + countt + "\n"); });
        richTextBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { richTextBox1.AppendText("Counti = " + counti + "\n"); });
    }
    richTextBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { richTextBox1.AppendText("Done"); });
    cuttedtosend = new List<byte>();
    for (int index = filetosend.Count() - countt; index < filetosend.Count(); index++)
    {
        //richTextBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { richTextBox1.AppendText(index + "this is 2 \n"); });
        cuttedtosend.Add(filetosend[index]);
    }
    Sender.Send(cuttedtosend.ToArray());
    countt -= countt;
    return "";
}
```

And here is my receive code:

```
private async void StartReceiving()
{
    List<byte> neededbytes = new List<byte>();
    receivedbyte = new byte[InputForm.s];
    Receiver.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("0"), 6112));
    Receiver.Listen(1000);
    string filename = "Downloadedfile";
    bool cont = false;
    while (true)
    {
        Client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
        Client = Receiver.Accept();
        int filesize = 0;
        byte[] receivechecker = new byte[100];
        Client.Receive(receivechecker);
        if(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receivechecker).Contains("filesize#"))
        {
            filesize = Convert.ToInt32(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receivechecker).Remove(0, 9));
            Client.Receive(receivechecker);
        }
        if (Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receivechecker).Contains("#100254#"))
        {
            string[] splttedtext = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receivechecker.ToArray()).Split('#');
            if (splttedtext[0] == "mess")
            {
                MessageBox.Show(splttedtext[2]);
            }
            else if (splttedtext[0] == "filename")
            {
                //MessageBox.Show(splttedtext[2]);
                filename = splttedtext[2];
                //filename.Replace(@"\", @"/");
                cont = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            List<byte> tosave = new List<byte>();
            richTextBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { richTextBox1.AppendText(filesize.ToString() + "\n"); });
            int countt = filesize / 7000;
            FileStream writer = File.Create("DownloadedFile.jpg");
            for (int counti = 0; counti < countt; counti++)
            {
                byte[] toadd = new byte[7000];
                richTextBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { richTextBox1.AppendText("Counti = " + counti.ToString() + "\n"); });
                Client.Receive(toadd);
                writer.Write(toadd,0,toadd.Count());
                neededbytes.AddRange(toadd);
                filesize -= 7000;
            }
            richTextBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { richTextBox1.AppendText(filesize.ToString() + "\n"); });
            byte[] toadds = new byte[filesize];
            Client.Receive(toadds);
            writer.Write(toadds,0,toadds.Count());
            writer.Close();
            neededbytes.AddRange(toadds);
            filesize -= filesize;
        }
   }
```

Thanks in advance :D

Edit:
I just tried Sending a 7mb text file and it reached complete.......

Comment: You're not disposing of anything here.

Comment: if by that u mean adding writer.Flush() then i just added that but still files reach corrupted.

Comment: That code is an illegible mess. Format it, that will help you know what is going on.

Answer (score 3):

The most immediate problem is that you're saving bytes that you didn't necessarily receive. For example, you have:

```
        for (int counti = 0; counti < countt; counti++)
        {
            byte[] toadd = new byte[7000];
            richTextBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { richTextBox1.AppendText("Counti = " + counti.ToString() + "\n"); });
            Client.Receive(toadd);
            writer.Write(toadd,0,toadd.Count());
            neededbytes.AddRange(toadd);
            filesize -= 7000;
        }
```

The documentation for `Receive` says that the method will receive *up to* the number of bytes you request. It's not uncommon for it to return fewer bytes than you requested, especially at the end of the file (since it couldn't receive more than the file length).

You need to write:

```
var bytesRead = Client.Receive(toadd);
writer.Write(toadd, 0, bytesRead);  // only write as many bytes as you've read
```

In general, your code is pretty convoluted, and you have several other possible problems just waiting to bite you. For example, the code that sends the file size sleeps for 500 ms, which just happens to be enough time for the receiver to read just the number of bytes sent. Without that sleep, your code would fail.

You have code to receive the file name, but no code to send it.

I would suggest that you eliminate the ASCII tags and send things in binary. Below is your rewritten Send method.

```
private string SendFile(string tosend, string tosendname)
{
    ipadd = IPAddress.Parse(textBox2.Text);
    ep = new IPEndPoint(ipadd, 6112);
    Sender = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
    Sender.Connect(ep);

    byte[] filetosend = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(tosend);
    byte[] filesizeBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(filetosend.Length);
    Sender.Send(filesizeBytes); // sends the length as an integer

    // note: You could use Socket.Send(filetosend) here.
    // but I'll show an example of sending in chunks.
    int totalBytesSent = 0;
    while (totalBytesSent < filetosend.Length)
    {
        int bytesLeft = filetosend.Length - totalBytesSent;
        int bytesToSend = Math.Min(bytesLeft, 7000);
        Sender.Send(filetosend, totalBytesSent, bytesToSend);
        richTextBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate 
            { richTextBox1.Append(totalBytesSent + " bytes sent\n"); });
        totalBytesSent += bytesToSend;
    }
    richTextBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { richTextBox1.AppendText("Done"); });
    return "";
}
```

The receiver code is similarly simplified:

```
private async void StartReceiving()
{
    Receiver.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("0"), 6112));
    Receiver.Listen(1000);
    string filename = "Downloadedfile";
    bool cont = false;
    while (true)
    {
        Client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
        Client = Receiver.Accept();

        // read the length
        byte[] filesizeBytes = new byte[4];
        int totalBytesReceived = 0;
        while (totalBytesReceived < 4)
        {
            int bytesRead = Client.Receive(
                filesizeBytes, totalBytesReceived, 4-totalBytesReceived);
            totalBytesReceived += bytesRead;
        }
        int filesize = BitConverter.ToInt32(filesizeBytes);
        richTextBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate 
            { richTextBox1.AppendText(filesize.ToString() + "\n"); });

        // now read the file
        using (FileStream writer = File.Create("DownloadedFile.jpg"))
        {
            byte[] readBuffer = new byte[7000];
            totalBytesReceived = 0;
            while (totalBytesReceived < filesize)
            {
                int bytesToRead = Math.Min(7000, filesize - totalBytesReceived);
                int bytesRead = Client.Receive(readBuffer, 0, bytesToRead);
                totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
                writer.Write(readBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
                richTextBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate 
                    { richTextBox1.AppendText("Read " + bytesRead.ToString() + "bytes\n"); });
            }
            richTextBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate 
                { richTextBox1.AppendText("Done. " + totalBytesRead.ToString() + " bytes\n"); });
        }
   }
```

If you want to send the file name, then I would suggest converting it to UTF8 (`Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(filename)`), then send an int (4 bytes) that says how long it is, and then the buffer. To receive it, read the 4-byte filename length like I showed how to read the file size, then that many bytes for the file name, and convert back to a string (`Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, filenameLength)`).

Please excuse any typos or minor errors in the code. I'm doing this from memory and trying to keep somewhat with your coding style.

Comment: thnx alot, I am still beginning with socket programming(infact i am still a beginner programmer :D) and i dont really know very much about it, and i still dont completely understand what u said but i am going to take ur advice. if i could +1 u, i would but i cant cuz i need 15 rep. Oh and about the send filename thing, i deleted it for now cuz it was causing some errors.

Answer (score 1):

i suspect that you are expecting the same blocks that you send to be received; ie that record boundaries will be preserved. This is not so. TCP guarantees that every byte sent will be received and that order is preserved; but you could do 1 large 10k send and receive 10k 1 byte messages.